# ReactJS (beginner) Using Youtube API - Returned Object Not Allowing Me to Access VideoId Property

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, youtube-api

I'm a React beginner, so go easy on me..

I'm making a really really basic app right now that I will expand on later..

Right now I'm simply trying to get React to pull a JSON object from Youtube with channel data, store the returned list of videos (I guess in state?), and then pull the video IDs so that I can throw them in an object and randomize them for playback later.

My code is pulling the data alright, but at the moment I can't seem to access the "videoId" property of each video's ID... I can't for the life of me, understand why the video ID objects are accessible, but not their properties within..

It seems like YouTube API is returning an array of objects.. so I thought I should be able to do this:

videos[0].id.videoId

but this is giving errors... however videos[0].id seems to work, so I'm lost..

What am I doing wrong? Am I using state wrong? Am I accessing the object properties wrong?

See below for console logs in the example:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import YouTube from "react-youtube";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(">> [App.js] Inside Constructor", props);
    this.state = {
      videos: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var that = this;
    var API_key = "MY API KEY IS HERE (working) ";
    var channelID = "UCs3o4RhBiP2wcwqkZR2QVLw";
    var maxResults = 10;
    var url =
      "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=" +
      API_key +
      "&channelId=" +
      channelID +
      "&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=" +
      maxResults;

    fetch(url)
      .then(function(response) {
        if (response.status >= 400) {
          throw new Error("Bad response from server");
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        that.setState({ videos: data.items });
        console.log(">> data items: ", data.items);
      });
  }

  render() {
    const opts = {
      height: "390",
      width: "640",
      playerVars: {
        // https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters
        autoplay: 1
      }
    };

    console.log(">> states = ", JSON.stringify(this.state.videos[0]));
    //logs :
    // >> states =  {"kind":"youtube#searchResult","etag":"\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/z_ggxomb8RCC1cd6Bx8IrkCUHxA\"","id":{"kind":"youtube#video","videoId":"IoId8_4mvT4"},"snippet":{"publishedAt":"2017-07-18T19:12:33.000Z","channelId":"UCs3o4RhBiP2wcwqkZR2QVLw","title":"WATCH in 360 - CP24 tours Toronto Island. July 18 2017","description":"Subscribe to CP24 to watch more videos: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCs3o4RhBiP2wcwqkZR2QVLw Connect with CP24: For the latest news visit: ...","thumbnails":{"default":{"url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IoId8_4mvT4/default.jpg","width":120,"height":90},"medium":{"url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IoId8_4mvT4/mqdefault.jpg","width":320,"height":180},"high":{"url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IoId8_4mvT4/hqdefault.jpg","width":480,"height":360}},"channelTitle":"CP24","liveBroadcastContent":"none"}}

    console.log(">> states = ", JSON.stringify(this.state.videos[0].id));
    //logs : ERROR :
    // >> states = ncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    // at App.render (App.js:50)
    // at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:13193)
    // at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:13155)

    return (
      <div className="App">
        {
          // using an NPM package for displaying YouTube Videos
          // will add this back when I get the videoIds pulling correctly..
          //<YouTube
          //   videoId={this.state.videos[1].videoId}
          //   opts={opts}
          //   onReady={this._onReady}
          // />
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request is asynchronous, so the videos will not be set on first render. `this.state.videos[0]` will give `undefined`, and trying to access `id` on that will result in your error.

You could instead e.g. keep an additional piece of state `loading` and just render `null` until your network request has finished.

**Example**

```
class App extends Component {
  state = { videos: [], loading: true };

  componentDidMount() {
    var that = this;
    var API_key = "MY API KEY IS HERE (working) ";
    var channelID = "UCs3o4RhBiP2wcwqkZR2QVLw";
    var maxResults = 10;
    var url =
      "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=" +
      API_key +
      "&channelId=" +
      channelID +
      "&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=" +
      maxResults;

    fetch(url)
      .then(function(response) {
        if (response.status >= 400) {
          throw new Error("Bad response from server");
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        that.setState({ videos: data.items, loading: false });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { loading, videos } = this.state;

    if (loading) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <YouTube
          videoId={videos[1].id.videoId}
          opts={{
            height: "390",
            width: "640",
            playerVars: {
              autoplay: 1
            }
          }}
          onReady={this._onReady}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Tholle! This is really helpful.. I suspected that the async request was an issue, but I wasn't sure how to check if it loaded or not, but this makes sense. I'll try it.